# Cannot resolve symbol 'R' in android after cloning project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've already tried many solutions from similar questions like 
(i) cleaning and rebuilding the project
(ii) invalidating the caches and restarting android studio
(iii) finding any errors in my project. (I doubt that it would be this as I have cloned a project that is used by all of my team)

This is my error log:

```
org.gradle.initialization.ReportedException: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':compileDebugRenderscript'.
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.exceptions.LocationAwareException: Execution failed for task ':compileDebugRenderscript'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileDebugRenderscript'.

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/therock/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/arm-linux-androideabi-ld''
    at com.android.ide.common.internal.WaitableExecutor.waitForTasksWithQuickFail(WaitableExecutor.java:147)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.RenderScriptProcessor.createSupportFilesHelper(RenderScriptProcessor.java:393)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.RenderScriptProcessor.createSupportFiles(RenderScriptProcessor.java:310)
    at com.android.builder.internal.compiler.RenderScriptProcessor.build(RenderScriptProcessor.java:220)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.compileAllRenderscriptFiles(AndroidBuilder.java:1280)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.RenderscriptCompile.taskAction(RenderscriptCompile.java:201)

Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/therock/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/arm-linux-androideabi-ld''

Caused by: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.NativeException: Could not start '/home/therock/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/arm-linux-androideabi-ld'
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:27)
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.WrapperProcessLauncher.start(WrapperProcessLauncher.java:36)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.ExecHandleRunner.run(ExecHandleRunner.java:68)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/therock/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.3/arm-linux-androideabi-ld" (in directory "/home/therock/android"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultProcessLauncher.start(DefaultProcessLauncher.java:25)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    ... 7 more
```

What could be the possible cause of this? Thanks.

Comment: I think this there is some missing package or wrongly named package `(in directory "/home/h8pathak/android"): error=2, No such file or directory` check for h8pathak package name and try to resolve accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It seems you dont have arm-linux-androideabi-ld in your sdk folder. Go in Android Studio Preferences > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK. In the "SDK Tools" part check the "Show Package Details" at the bottom right and verify if 25.0.3 is check under Android SDK Build-Tools.

It can be that.